# BETWEEN IN SQL to check a time between two times

Tags: sql, sql-server, between

Is it possible to check the time between ,let's say 19:00 to 08:00 of next day using `BETWEEN` ? I'm only using `time`.(not `datetime`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure:

WHERE NOT time BETWEEN '8:00' AND '19:00'

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from MyTable
where CAST(mytime as time) >= '19:00:00' 
   and CAST(mytime as time) < '08:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
select *
from MyTable
where Datetimecolumn >= convert(datetime,'2016-05-16 19:00:00') 
   and Datetimecolumn <=dateadd(hh,12,convert(datetime,'2016-05-16 19:00:00'))
```